# AngularJS Controller's filter not see ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**The code is finally works. I don't know why.**

I use self-defined filter to filer ng-repeat. **I put the code inside an Controller**

...

```
.controller('makeOrderController', function ($scope, $timeout, $ionicLoading) {
    $scope.searchMenuFilter = function () {
        return function (data) {
            if (data != undefined) {
                var result = JSLINQ(data)
                    .Where(function (item) { return item.name.match(/\b(\w)/g).join('') == $scope.searchKeyword });
                console.log($scope)
                console.log($scope.searchKeyword)
                return result.items;
            }
            else {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

And here is the HTML

```
 <ion-list>
     <ion-item ng-repeat="item in menuData | filter:searchMenuFilter()" class="item item-button-right" item="item" can-swipe="true">  </ion-item> 
</ion-list>
        <input type="search" placeholder="Tìm kiếm" ng-change="searchMenu()" ng-model="searchKeyword">
```

The console show me it don't see the showKeyword model ? What is it ? It still see another defined model in inside controller, but ng-model it not.

Comment: Can you provide the `ng-repeat` loop as well as the code around it?

Comment: The code is updated :)

Comment: is the textbox in the ng-repeat?

Comment: It's out side.  I have udpated the code :)

Comment: I'm not seeing where searchKeyword is actually defined (it's not defined anywhere in the code you posted). Also you do you mean searchKeyboard or showKeyboard?

Comment: The code is finally works. I don't know why. Thanks for my brothers help me :)

Comment: should always always always use object reference in `ng-model`....golden rule is *always have a dot in `ng-model`*

Comment: Thanks for Charlietfl'sreply :) This is the  naming convention i need to know :)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have some directives that are defining searchKeyboard, then the error you are receiving is correct. Please see code below for example.

```
.controller('makeOrderController', function ($scope, $timeout, $ionicLoading) {
  // Check if searchKeyword exists or declare it
  $scope.searchKeyword = $scope.searchKeyword || {};

  $scope.searchMenuFilter = function () {
    return function (data) {
      if (data != undefined) {
          var result = JSLINQ(data)
              .Where(function (item) { 
                // searchKeyword is not defined in this code snippet
                return (item.name.match(/\b(\w)/g).join('') == $scope.searchKeyword);
              });
          console.log($scope);
          console.log($scope.searchKeyword); // Not defined in code snippet
          return result.items;
      }
      else {
          return null;
      }
    }
  }
});
```